# ZeroMQ how to get binded address in pyzmq

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using ZMQ bindings in Python, and I want to bind clients to some port, and then send that location to other clients to connect.
Now this is basic binding code:

```
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
...
subscriber.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:12345")
```

What I need to get is external address, not `0.0.0.0`,  let say my pc has IP `192.168.1.10`, I need to get "tcp://192.168.1.10:12345" and send that to other clients, because sending `tcp://0.0.0.0:12345` is useless.

How can I get external IP of interface that ZMQ used to create a socket?

There can be the number of NIC on pc, and if I just try to get external IP using normal socket it could be invalid, cause I don't know what NIC ZMQ used.

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0 (INADDR_ANY) is the "any" address (non-routable meta-address). It is a way to specify "any IPv4-interface at all".
This means that all your interfaces are listening on port 12345.

To list all your network interfaces I would recommend to use a library like [this](http://code.google.com/p/python-ifconfig/)

If you are using linux you could do this:

```
import array
import struct
import socket
import fcntl

SIOCGIFCONF = 0x8912  #define SIOCGIFCONF
BYTES = 4096          # Simply define the byte size

# get_iface_list function definition 
# this function will return array of all 'up' interfaces 
def get_iface_list():
    # create the socket object to get the interface list
    sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    # prepare the struct variable
    names = array.array('B', '\0' * BYTES)

    # the trick is to get the list from ioctl
    bytelen = struct.unpack('iL', fcntl.ioctl(sck.fileno(), SIOCGIFCONF, struct.pack('iL', BYTES, names.buffer_info()[0])))[0]

    # convert it to string
    namestr = names.tostring()

    # return the interfaces as array
    return [namestr[i:i+32].split('\0', 1)[0] for i in range(0, bytelen, 32)]

# now, use the function to get the 'up' interfaces array
ifaces = get_iface_list()

# well, what to do? print it out maybe... 
for iface in ifaces:
 print iface
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP address of your machine, this might help:

```
def get_ip_data(ether_adapter):
    ip_data = os.popen("ifconfig " + ether_adapter)
    for line in ip_data:
        match2 = re.search(r'inet addr:+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)', line)
        if match2:
            ip_ = match2.group(1)
            return ip_
if __name__=="__main__":
    ethernet_card = "wlp3s0"   ---> This might be etho or whatever you want
    ip_of_the_machine = get_ip_data(ethernet_card)
```